# undefined reference to pthread_wait compiled with -pthread & -lpthread

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, pthreads

I am getting the following errors:

```
assign4.o: In function `main':
assign4.c:(.text+0x76f): undefined reference to `pthread_broadcast'
assign4.o: In function `threadFunc':
assign4.c:(.text+0x15fd): undefined reference to `pthread_wait'
assign4.c:(.text+0x17f3): undefined reference to `pthread_wait'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When compiling with:

```
gcc -pthread assign4.c -o assign4 -lm
```

or

```
gcc assign4.c -o assign4 -lm -lpthread
```

Here is the call to pthread_broadcast:

```
while (killCount < numThreads) {
    while (waitCount < numThreads);
    waitCount = 0;
    pthread_broadcast();
}
```

The calls to pthread_wait:

```
pthread_wait();
for (i = 0; i < partInfo.groupSize; i++) {  
    for (j = 0; j < numParts; j++) {
        gravitation(bodies[i], parts[i]);
    }
}
if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx) != 0) {
    printf("Error locking mutex.\n");
    return -1;
}
waitCount++;
if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx) != 0) {
    printf("Error unlocking mutex.\n");
    return -1;
}
pthread_wait();
if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx) != 0) {
    printf("Error locking mutex.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried compiling with -pthread and -lpthread and it's just not working. I figure it must be something really obvious that I'm missing but I can't figure out what.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm using a school server that it has to be able to compile on and which others have had success compiling pthread programs on. Here is the gcc -v information:  

    Using built-in specs.  
    Target: x86_64-redhat-linux  
    Configured with: <removed>  
    Thread model: posix  
    gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings with `-Wall` and GCC will tell you that `pthread_wait` and `pthread_broadcast` have not been declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function called `pthread_wait()`, it may be [pthread_cond_wait()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html). That's why you are getting a linker error. When the linker unable to find the function definition it will give `undefined reference to` error. so you are getting

```
assign4.c:(.text+0x15fd): undefined reference to `pthread_wait'
assign4.c:(.text+0x17f3): undefined reference to `pthread_wait'
```

I think for `pthread_broadcast()` also same error, it should be [pthread_cond_broadcast()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not looking for [`pthread_cond_broadcast`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) and [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html)?

There don't seem to be any `pthread_wait` and `pthread_broadcast` functions, especially not ones that take no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wait for some time once you are inside the thread , you can try using sleep(); and provide the number of seconds as argument. If that does not work then try out pthread_cond_wait(); 
You can refer to [pthread tutorials](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)

and yes the compile error is thrown because there is no such function as pthread_wait().